# Merge from development introduces older state of files

Tags: xcode, git, merge

I have a strange problem in git. We are using git with bitbucket and sourcetree. We are building an iOS app in Swift with Xcode.

To illustrate the problem let's say I have a `var string = "Old state"` which is on my Development branch. I made a featureBranch1 where I changed string to `"New state"`. I created a PR and merged this change into Development.

At the same time as featureBranch1 I created a featureBranch2. I changed files unrelated to `var string`.
Now there were some changes in Development made by other developers, which caused a merge conflict in my main .pbxproj file. I decided to merge Development into my featureBranch2. Something went wrong here that I couldn't figure out. I received a "failed to write index" error. Yet the merge from development did succeed. The merge conflict was solved and I merged my featureBranch2 into Development.

After the merge of featureBranch1 I created a featureBranch3. Now there was also a merge conflict in this branch and I tried to merge Development into this branch. What happened is that `var string` is changed back to "Old state" in my featureBranch3. So it tries to change `var string` back to before the changes of featureBranch1. Now every other branch where I try to merge development in, changes `var string` back to "Old state".

Of course in the real situation this happens for multiple files with multiple changes and it is really tedious to change everything back manually, before merging any featureBranch to Development.

What could've gone wrong? Has anyone ever experienced this? And what could I do to fix this problem. There is still one more featureBranch open with a merge conflict, and this branch has a lot of changes and I don't look forward to the same problem when merging Development into this featureBranch.

I hope it's clear what is happening here.. And I really hope someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: _I received a "failed to write index" error_ From whom? Who "spoke" this error? Git? Xcode? Be specific.

Comment: _I  created a featureBranch3_ Starting from what branch? Please, be specific.

Comment: Perhaps it might be good to show a small example of what’s happening. Perhaps through screenshots or a recorded video or something. It’s quite hard to tell what is happening. Or if you could provide a concise set of steps that you are following to replicate this issue that would be good too. It def sounds like something is going wrong but I’m not sure what. Are you particularly new to git? I know it might not help fix the situation but I always found GitKraken makes it really easy to visualise the history which might help.

Comment: Hey! Yes I figured it would be a bit too concise. @matt the featureBranches are always branched from development. The failed to write index was in sourcetree.

Comment: @Fogmeister Having examined sourcetree a bit closer, there was a point in which I accidentally merged the not most recent commit into my featureBranch2 and went on from there. Could this be the cause of my errors? I'm not that new to git, but I must say I can be a bit chaotic when I have conflicts.